# How can I remove an attached jQuery function programatically?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In `$.ready()` I have declared a `click` function as shown below

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btnClk").click(function(clkevent){
        //Doing Something Here
        clkevent.preventDefault();
    });

});
```

I want to remove this `click()` from `$("#btnClk")` in another javaScript function. How can I do this?

Comment: All of the information you require is at http://api.jquery.com/off/

Comment: Small suggestion to  google before posting here dude.

Comment: @VeeKayBee I searched google. Ended up with `unbind` function. But i wanted to remove only one or two functions.

Comment: @SubinJacob just to inform you. People are more expecting complex issues. Some guys may down vote you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the problems with the proposed solutions is they remove all click event handlers registered, which may not be desired.

A solution to this is to separate the handler method out to a common scope shared by the both the participating methods then use that method reference along with [.off()](http://api.jquery.com/off/) to resolve this

```
function btnclickHandler(clkevent){
    //Doing Something Here
    clkevent.preventDefault();
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btnClk").click(btnclickHandler);
});

$("#btnClk").off('click', btnclickHandler);
```

Comment: The off() method removes event handlers that were attached with .on().-- from api.jQuery.com. Here not attached with on(), any probs?

Comment: @SubinJacob it won't cause a problem since `.bind()` is currently (almost) synonymous with `.on()`.

Answer (score 1):

Old School

```
 $("#btnClk").unbind('click');
```

New School

```
 $("#btnClk").off('click');
```

Comment: This will remove all handlers if there were others added. If that's not desirable, you have to pass the handler you want removed, or use event namespaces

Answer (score 1):

To register a click handler you *should* be using `.on('click', ...)` instead of `.click` - the latter can cause confusion because the same function is also used to *trigger* a click event.

To *unregister* the handler, use `.off('click')`

Please see the caveats at http://api.jquery.com/off/ regarding function handlers, name spaces, etc (my emphasis):

> If a simple event name such as "click" is provided, **all events of that type** (both direct and delegated) **are removed from the elements in the jQuery set**.

and

> A handler can also be removed by specifying the function name in the handler argument.

Note that in the latter case you can't specify the function name if the function never had  a name in the first place, as in the code in the question where the handler is an *anonymous* function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [unbind](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) for this .

```
$('#btnClk).unbind('click');
```

[almost same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10619531/how-to-deattach-event-and-attach-new-one-in-jquery)

Comment: `.unbind` is the out-of-date way of doing this

Comment: I am old school guy .. http://stackoverflow.com/a/16476792/779158 please check this for new solution . I don't want to copy his answer also in my answer. Thanks for comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using [off()](http://api.jquery.com/off/):

```
$('#btnClk').off('click');
```

This will remove all click event handlers from the `btnClk`.